# How to convert a folder of pngs to pdf in linux mint

Tags: pdf, png, linux-mint

I have tried many options to do this but none worked. Also i have like 14k pngs in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

With **ImageMagick** v7 as follows:

```
magick mogrify -format PDF *.png
```

If you only have v6 **ImageMagick**, use:

```
mogrify -format PDF *.png
```

---

Or, if that is too long for your shell's maximum argument length:

```
for f in *.png; do
   magick "$f" "${f%.*}".pdf
done
```

---

Or, if you want to talk advantage of all those lovely CPU cores for which you paid Intel so handsomely, install **GNU Parallel** and do them in parallel:

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | parallel -0 magick {} {.}.pdf
```

Or, as above but with **ImageMagick** v6:

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | parallel -0 convert {} {.}.pdf
```

Comment: it makes separate pdfs for each png. How to combine all the pngs in one pdf?